# number of consecutive integers sum to 2020*2019

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

[image]

Attached picture shows the problem - here is how i tried: suppose n, n+1, ... n+k sums up to the same value, then

(2n+k)(k+1)=2020*2019=2^2*3*5*101*673

there are 3*16=48 total number of factors including 1, 2 3 4 5 101, 673, 2019 2020 etc. The answer should be half of 48 take away 1. Is this right?

Comment: This reads like a current contest problem.  What is the source of your question??

Comment: this is last year's problem not this year's

Comment: Note that the claimed sum in your title is twice $T$.

Comment: Why did you remove the source of the question, @user526427.  You first commented in was from MathCounts last year.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2n+k$ and $k+1$ have opposite parity, so all the factors of $2$ have to go into one of them.  The $3$ in your $48$ assumes you can put one $2$ into each of them, which is not true.